How to implement DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler class in cas v6.6.15
In cas v6.3.7.4 we got this class impemented to capture after google/facebook auth, the process and take actions before reject or sucess login.
public class DelegatedClientAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractPac4jAuthenticationHandler  {

Now in cas v6.6.15 this class doesn´t exists and i donn´t identify how to acomplish the same override on the new classes.
somebody can help me point me which class i need to override to acomplish the same?
